# Can't bind multi-part identifier

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to run this query which should select the average product per category. I'm using datagrip and my error is:

> The multi-part identifier "main.Catégorie.Libellé_Cat" could not be bound

Shouldn't it be able to bind the correct column to the select statement ?

```sql
SELECT 
    main.Catégorie.Libellé_Cat, AVG(Moyenne_de_produits)
FROM 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Moyenne_de_produits
     FROM Magasin.main.Produit P
     INNER JOIN main.Catégorie C ON C.Code_Cat = P.Catégorie) AS Mdp
GROUP BY 
    main.Catégorie.Libellé_Cat
```

This is my project structure

[image]

This is the relational diagram:

[image]

Comment: You aliased the query `Mdp` *not* `Main`.

Comment: FYI [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/) and should be avoided. You are far better off aliasing your objects in the `FROM` and using those to qualify your columns. This avoids the use of a feature that will be deprecated and possibly removed in a future version. You *do* alias your objects here, but then try to reference it not by its alias, and in a different scope.

Comment: @Larnu Sorry but i'm really confused on how to go about using 2 part naming with this query. Since i'm using a sub-query where could I write the aliases for the outer SELECT ?

Comment: The only object available to your outer query is the `count(*)`. If you don't know how to write your query, show some sample data and desired results.

Comment: `SELECT cat, Moyenne_de_produits
FROM(
        SELECT  AVG(Qte_Stk) AS Moyenne_de_produits, C.Libellé_Cat AS cat
        FROM main.Produit P
        INNER JOIN main.Catégorie C ON C.Code_Cat = P.Catégorie
        GROUP BY C.Libellé_Cat
) as main
GROUP BY cat, Moyenne_de_produits
`
Ok so I was able to make it run. Can anyone confirm if this is the desired 2 part syntax @Larnu was talking about ?

Comment: I can't format it properly ..

Comment: You can't post formatted code in the comments @uwponcel, you need to [edit] your question.

Comment: And as I stated, you aliased the query **`Mdp`**; that is its alias, **`Mdp`**. `main.Catégorie.Libellé_Cat` has no meaning because: 1. You aliased the object that that column belong to as `C` 2. That alias is in a different scope; again you aliased the subquery `Mdp`. 3. Your subquery has no column `Libellé_cat`.